# Chained ajax call, second call returns 0

Tags: ajax, json

working with PayPal and running some ajax requests. The first ajax request gives me some data that I need to pass to the second ajax request. The first request is working fine, and I am getting the preapproval key, I then want to pass that preaproval key back to wordpress and save it. The only way I can think of to pass the preaproval key back to wordpress is to run another ajax request chained off the first.

JS

```
var settings = {
            "url": url,
            "method": "POST",
            "data": {
                'action': 'talknow_preapproval',
                'user_id': user_id,
                'therapist_id': therapist_id,
                'cost_per_session': cost_per_session
            },
            "headers": {},
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                alert( 'An error occurred... ' );
                window.console.log(
                    'status code ' + jqXHR.status + ', the error thrown was ' + errorThrown + ', the response text: ' + jqXHR.responseText + ', text status: ' + textStatus
                );
                window.console.log( 'full jqXHR object:' + jqXHR );
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                console.info( 'ajax request successful' );
                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                //check if the result has errors, if yes deal with them
                if( typeof result.error !== 'undefined' && result.error.length > 0 ) {
                    alert('Looks there was a problem launching the video, please contact support');
                    console.warn('There was an error: ');
                    console.log(result.error);
                }
                //console.log(result);
                if( result.preapprovalKey  ) {
                    var ppUrl = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=' + encodeURIComponent(result.preapprovalKey);
                    console.info('we are redirecting you to paypal' + ppUrl);
                    //window.location.replace(ppUrl); // take user to paypal so that they can enter their card details and approve
                }

            }
        }

        $.ajax( settings ).done( function( response ) {
            console.info('ajax request done');
        } ).then(function(response) {
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            var saveSettings = {
                "url": url,
                "method": "POST",
                "data": {
                    'action': 'talknow_save_preapproval',
                    'user_id': user_id,
                    'therapist_id': therapist_id,
                    'cost_per_session': cost_per_session,
                    'preapproval_key': result.preapproval_key
                },
                "headers": {},
                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    alert( 'An error occurred... ' );
                    window.console.log(
                        'status code ' + jqXHR.status + ', the error thrown was ' + errorThrown + ', the response text: ' + jqXHR.responseText + ', text status: ' + textStatus
                    );
                    window.console.log( 'full jqXHR object:' + jqXHR );
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    console.info('save preapproval ajax request success');
                    console.log( response );
                }
            }
            $.ajax( saveSettings ).done( function( response ) {
                console.log( response );
                console.info('save preapproval ajax request done');
            } );
        });
```

wp add_action

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_talknow_preapproval', [ $this, 'talknow_preapproval' ] );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_talknow_save_preapproval', [ $this, 'talknow_save_preapproval' ] );
```

The php functions are below

```
public function talknow_preapproval() {
    if( 'POST' !== $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) {
        wp_die( __( 'oh no, something has gone very wrong' ) );
    } else {
        $user_id = isset( $_POST[ 'user_id' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'user_id' ] : '';
        $therapist_id = isset( $_POST[ 'therapist_id' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'therapist_id' ] : '';
        $cost_per_session = isset( $_POST[ 'cost_per_session' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'cost_per_session' ] : '';

        if( !empty( $user_id ) && !empty( $therapist_id ) && !empty( $cost_per_session ) ) {
            $user_id = intval( $user_id );
            $therapist_id = intval( $therapist_id );
            $cost_per_session = (float) $cost_per_session;

            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL        => "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Preapproval", CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "cancelUrl=redacted_for_security&currencyCode=GBP&endingDate=2017-05-10&maxAmountPerPayment=50.00&maxNumberOfPayments=1&maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments=50.00&pinType=NOT_REQUIRED&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=redacted_for_security%2F&startingDate=2017-05-09", 
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                            "cache-control: no-cache", "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "x-paypal-application-id: APP-80W284485P519543T", "x-paypal-request-data-format: NV", "x-paypal-response-data-format: JSON", "x-paypal-security-password: redacted_for_security", "x-paypal-security-signature: redacted_for_security", "x-paypal-security-userid: redacted_for_security",
                    ),
            ) );

            $response = curl_exec( $curl );
            $err = curl_error( $curl );

            curl_close( $curl );

            if( $err ) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
                die();
            } else {
                echo $response;
                die();
            }

        } else {
            _e( 'There was a problem with the preapproval process, please contact support' );
            die();
        }
    }
}

public function talknow_save_preapproval() {
    if( 'POST' !== $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) {
        wp_die( __( 'oh no, something has gone very wrong' ) );
    } else {
        $user_id = isset( $_POST[ 'user_id' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'user_id' ] : '';
        $therapist_id = isset( $_POST[ 'therapist_id' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'therapist_id' ] : '';
        $cost_per_session = isset( $_POST[ 'cost_per_session' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'cost_per_session' ] : '';
        $preapproval_key = isset( $_POST[ 'preapproval_key' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'preapproval_key' ] : '';

        if( ! empty( $user_id ) && ! empty( $therapist_id ) && ! empty( $cost_per_session ) && ! empty( $preapproval_key ) ) {
            $user_id = intval( $user_id );
            $therapist_id = intval( $therapist_id );
            $cost_per_session = (float) $cost_per_session;
            $preapproval_key = sanitize_text_field( $preapproval_key );

            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PreapprovalDetails",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "preapprovalKey=PA-6U047065P9760690U&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US",
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                            "cache-control: no-cache", "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "x-paypal-application-id: APP-80W284485P519543T", "x-paypal-request-data-format: NV", "x-paypal-response-data-format: JSON", "x-paypal-security-password: redacted_for_security", "x-paypal-security-signature: redacted_for_security", "x-paypal-security-userid: redacted_for_security",
                    ),
            ) );

            $response = curl_exec( $curl );
            $err = curl_error( $curl );

            curl_close( $curl );

            if( $err ) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
                die();
            } else {
                echo $response;
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The php functions are still work in progress, values have been hardcoded at this point. If anyone can help that would be great

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: ah, yes that probably would have helped.. I've actually solved the problem there was an error in the code the `$_POST['preapproval_key']` should have been `$_POST['preapprovalKey']` , both me and my buddy missed it..*sigh

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved the problem there was an error in the code the `$_POST['preapproval_key']` should have been `$_POST['preapprovalKey']` literally hours wasted....

Comment: happens to all of us